# Iphone 6 Splash Screen 400x600?

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen

I thought the iphone 6 size was 750 x 1334 but it wouldn't show up correctly. If I have the splashscreen as 400x600 then it shows up correctly. I don't understand ? Not too sure what I'm doing wrong with the LaunchScreen.storyboard .

Comment: Did you show that image full screen?

Comment: I think I did yes.

Comment: Regardless of what size an iPhone 6 is, your app should work on devices of different sizes. Are you using a UIImageView? Is the UIImageView constrained to the sides of its parent? Is its view mode set to Aspect Fit or Aspect Fill? For further help, post screen shots or even better, your entire project.